# Swift issue: set property called map

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3

I am upgrading my Swift project from 2.3 to 3.0 in XCode 8. I use Google Maps API and they have some boilerplate code as follows:

```
self.mapView.camera=camera
let marker = GMSMarker(position: camera.target)
marker?.snippet = "Hello World"
marker.map = self.mapView
```

However, my XCode 8 Swift compiler gives me an error on the last line:

```
Cannot assign to property; map is a method
```

I have no control over the properties in Google's GMSMarker class. So how can I set the 'map' property?

Comment: Something fish's going on here... did you already declare the marker somewhere else? How is it not throwing at error at the optional at `marker?.snippet = "Hello World"`, that seems like a problem. Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: obj-c properties have getter and setter behind. Your Xcode seems to see both of them, and one is `func map() -> GMSMapView?` and is getter, and secont one might be `func setMap(_ map: GMSMapView?)` and might be a setter